# CAML query not getting items in right order

Tags: 2013

I am trying this query, but it always return items in wrong order,

```
function getListItems() {
    var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Fruits');

    var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
    camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View>Query><Where><IsNotNull><FieldRef Name="FruitNames" /></IsNotNull></Where><OrderBy><FieldRef Name="FruitNo" Ascending="True" /></OrderBy></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="FruitNo" /><FieldRef Name="FruitNames" /></ViewFields></View>');

    this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

    clientContext.load(collListItem, 'Include(FruitNo, FruitNames)');
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}
```

Doesnot matter if its false or true i get same result `Name="FruitNo" Ascending="True"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have pasted the same code here, I guess you are missing opening brace `<` of `Query` tag.. Check once.